# object was probably modified after being freed with Python on Mac

Tags: python, numpy, malloc, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have the following code in a function:

```
phi = fourier_matrix(y, fs)
N = np.size(phi,axis=1)
x = np.ones(N)

for i in range(136):
    W_pk = np.diag(x)
    temp = pinv(np.dot(phi, W_pk))
    q_k = np.dot(temp, y)
    x = np.dot(W_pk, q_k)
```

where phi is (96,750), W_pk is (750,750) and q_k is (750,).

This throws the following error:

> Python(12001,0x7fff99d8b380) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc71aa37200: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

If I comment the last dot product the error does not appear.

I think I need to free memory in some way or maybe do the dot product in a different way?

Also, this only happens when I run it from a mac. On windows or linux it does not throw the error.

Python is 3.6 (tried with 3.7), and numpy is 1.14.5, also tried with 1.15

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I really need to make this work!

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT I: 
I tried this portion of the code on a jupyter notebook, and it didn't fail. This confused me even more! It fails when I run it in Visual Studio Code on a mac. The rest of my code, an algorithm to remove artifacts from a signal, works as it should until I add that last piece of code *x = np.dot(W_pk, q_k)*. Maybe it works on jupyter because I don't run the rest of the algorithm there? but as I said, it only crashes on that last dot product.

---

EDIT II: I added the piece of code above the for loop to this question, because I found that the problem is somehow related to how x is being used. You see it's declared above as a float64 ndarray. When it reaches the last line of the for loop, the dot product returns a complex128 (should be complex64, don't know what's happening there) and overwrites the x array. The first time works, but the second time it crashes when trying to overwrite. If I use a new variable for the dot product, say z, then it does not crash! not sure why... but I need to overwrite x in each iteration.

Furthermore, if I do something like this:

```
z = np.dot(W_pk, q_k)
x = abs(z) #I don't need complex numbers at this point
```

Then it crashes with the same error on the first dot product (presumably):

```
temp = pinv(np.dot(phi, W_pk))
```

Also, the memory consumption is not that bad, around 110M according some measurements, and the same algorithm does not crash on iPython with twice the memory usage. This is what I find the most obscure, why doesn't it crash on iPython??

Comment: Can you tell the value of `phi`?

Comment: Yes, phi is (96,750). I just edited the question.

Comment: To anyone looking at this post in the future, I never found a solution other than just run my algorithm in a linux VM. However, I think this is an optimization problem that I'll be forced to face later...